# Prestashop - Adding Fields To Address Form To Be Stored In A Different Sql Table

Tags: sql, prestashop

I've recently added Facebook authentication to my site, which results in the user automatically being directed to the Address page once they have authenticated. Those users logging in this way will not be shown the extra questions I had asked them during the normal checkout/registration process ('How did you hear about us ?', etc..).

My question is, how do I add these fields into the Address form and get them to be inserted into the ps_customer table as they would be if a user was registering using the traditional way ? I could add fields to the Address template/controller right now, but they would end up being saved in the ps_address table instead

Any help would be much appreciated,

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible but will need some work around.

After you added the fields to the address form, you have to overried the Address.php class. Do it as followed.

1) In **override/classes** folder find the **Address.php** file, and also open **classes/Address.php** file .

2) In file classes/Address.php file, find add function which will be as below

```
 /**
 * @see ObjectModel::add()
 */
public function add($autodate = true, $null_values = false)
{
    if (!parent::add($autodate, $null_values))
        return false;

    if (Validate::isUnsignedId($this->id_customer))
        Customer::resetAddressCache($this->id_customer);
    return true;
}
```

Copy that exact function to override/classess/Address.php file and place it in the class.

3) Just after the below code

```
  if (!parent::add($autodate, $null_values))
        return false;
```

Write down your code to insert the extra fields to another table. Just get the POSTed values and write you won sql query to insert it into customers table or any other tables if you need.

Thank you

Comment: Thanks for that @altafhussain  Webserver is borking at the following though, nothing in the logs:     

[`$foundus = Tools::getValue('foundus');
$firstname = Tools::getValue('firstname');
$lastname = Tools::getValue('lastname');

$query = array(
 'table' => 'ps_customer',
 'data' => array('foundus' => pSQL($foundus)),
 'where' => 'firstname = '.pSQL($firstname).' AND lastname = '.pSQL($lastname)
 ); 
      
Db::getInstance()->update($query['table'], $query['data'], $query['where']);`]

Comment: why not you use simple query method like below, because i dont understand your query formatting in your comment. Do it like Db::getInstance()->update('ps_customer', $data, 'firstname = "'.$firstname.'"'); . The 500 error is not the database query error, but is due to your server problem(or any other problem).

Comment: Ended up finding the 5 different settings for Prestashop to show SQL errors. Prestashop automatically adds the ps_ prefix to the tables queried. Removed that and it works like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome, and that is good that you find out the problem. I missed that point :P